# Kobayashi Maru in Star Trek: Next Generation

Tags: star-trek, kobayashi-maru

Was there anyone tested with [Kobayashi Maru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru) in Star Trek: Next Generation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not on screen, but in the novel [*A Rock and a Hard Place*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/A_Rock_and_a_Hard_Place) there's one person, a maverick who will be a temporary replacement for Riker, that had an unusual solution.  Also in the short story *'Til Death* (part of the [*The Sky's the Limit*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Sky%27s_the_Limit) anthology), Riker's attempted solution is given.

I'm not going to say more about what was done or how, since that would be spoilers, but you can also find a little more info on Memory Alpha in their article on the [*Kobayashi Maru* scenario](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_scenario).  The direct link to the section with non-canon references is [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_scenario#Apocrypha).  (That article also states a "similar" test was used in the 24th century, so it seems by *The Next Generation* they were using a different test.

Answer (score 16):

Not exactly the same, but Deanna Troi was given the [Bridge Officer's Test](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bridge_Officer%27s_test) -  where she was ultimately forced to sacrifice Geordi La Forge to save the ship.

This took place in the Series 7 episode '[Thine Own Self](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_%28episode%29)'.

Comment: Initially the Bridge Officer’s Test required subjects to sacrifice Wesley, but no-one ever failed to do so.